# Parsing XML inside a linq query

Tags: xml, linq

I have a list of pages collected from my database. Each page has an XML field, which looks something like this:

```
<items>
  <item id="153"/>
  <item id="147"/>
</items>
```

Now I only want the pages which points to a specific id within the XML. So something like this:

```
var pages = GetAll().Where(p => p.XmlField //this is where i'm lost
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
p.XmlField.Descendants().Where(x => x.Attribute("id") == id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check whether *any* `item` within the `XmlField` has the right ID:

```
var pages = GetAll().Where(p => p.XmlField
                                 .Descendants("item")
                                 .Any(x => (int) x.Attribute("id") == id));
```

Alternatively you *might* want to use something like:

```
var pages = from page in GetAll()
            from item in page.XmlField.Descendants("item")
            where (int) item.Attribute("id") == id
            select page;
```

That will give you repeats of pages if the XML has the same ID twice though.